# Where to put Pi-user's startup scripts (Raspbian, X11)?

Tags: raspbian, boot, desktop

Running *Raspbian* desktop. [ I'm afraid I had not much experience using Linux in general, and none with *systemd* ] : where, praytell, should I put a startup shell script to run once upon my user ("Pi" of course) auto-logs-in at the desktop ? 
The script I have in mind is meant to automate the start'n'forking of things like *autocutsel* and *x2vnc*, instead of launching them "manually" each time over.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is to put startup tasks in the users .xinitrc file (`/home/pi/.xinitrc` in this case).  This should launch when the desktop start up.  Just make sure the file has executable permissions.

I used this to start up a kiosk GUI app on a RasPi when the user was auto-logged in. 
 Here's an example script I used to start up the Python based app:

```
#!/bin/sh
xset -dpms
xset s off
cd ~/app_dir
exec python kiosk_app.py
```

Comment: This method did  [edited] **not** work for me : Any _/home/pi/.xinitrc_ script is ignored in the boot process (not executed, not sourced...)   2. An _/home/pi/xsession_ **gets** executed, however it thus _replaces_ rather than complement the regular _xsession_ thus does not start a full desktop environment and session.  3.What **does** 100% work for me is to have my custom init script called  from the _/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart_  cf [link](https://www.wikihow.com/Execute-a-Script-at-Startup-on-the-Raspberry-Pi)

Comment: What I have works just fine in my setup, but it was from about a year ago so there may have been changes to how Raspbian boots since then.

Comment: I didn't doubt your setting works for your needs. Our situations differ, first - as you said - our versions of the Raspbian OS; second, the programs I want launched  apparently cannot be run too early, but only after the LXDE (PIXEL) desktop is in place - which is what _autostart_ affords.